# How to add condition in ARM Bicep template?

Tags: azure, arm, conditional-statements, infrastructure-as-code, azure-bicep

Let’s say, I want to deploy a separate resource only if `param isProduction bool`
is `true`.
Is that possible with Bicep?

I could not find this in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a syntax `if(isProduction)` that can be used after `=`, for example:

```
param isProduction bool

resource prodWebApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2020-12-01' = if (isProduction) {
  name: 'MyWebApp'
  ...<other props>...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer already given, not only can the whole resource be deployed based on a condition, but also individual properties of a resource can be changed for a specific environment using conditional ternary operator. The following is an example for Azure Front Door, where only in the production environment the Premium Tier is used:

```
resource profile 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles@2020-09-01' = {
  name: 'azureFrontDoor'
  location: 'global'
  sku: {
    name: isProduction ? 'Premium_AzureFrontDoor' : 'Standard_AzureFrontDoor'
  }
  tags: tags
}
```